# Pattern match on copy method of case classes

Tags: scala

I would like to pattern match an object if it implements a custom trait that I created (i.e. `Status`) **and** possesses a `copy` method provided by case classes. Is that possible in Scala?

```
status match {
  // How to pattern match for copy method support?
  // Is there a common trait we can leverage? or even a structural type construct?
  case s: Status with ???Copy??? => 
    s.copy(status = "NEW")
  case _ =>
    println("No status or no copy support")
    status
}
```

Comment: Thanks @syrion , I did not see this SO post. It does somewhat answer my question: there is no common interface, there could be workarounds. Not for my case though it seems (my case class and trait are not an exact match on the fields, hence defining a copy structural type on the trait won't be sufficient).

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I was curious and actually started to do research and found that old question. :-\